# How to check site availability and route based on availability

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager, azure-front-door

The users try to access https://site1.com hosted through Azure App Service.

I want to check if https://site1.com is available, then route the user to site1

If site1 is unavailable, reroute the user to https://site2.com

Should I use `Azure Traffic Manager` or `Front Door` or something else that is more suited to address the situation? TIA

Answer (score 1):

Both Azure Traffic Manager & Azure Front Door seems to fit your requirement. Both of them are global load balancers provides a range of traffic-routing methods and backend health monitoring options to suit different application needs and automatic failover scenarios. Both are resilient to failures, including failures to an entire Azure region.
[Compare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/load-balancing-overview#decision-tree-for-load-balancing-in-azure) the endpoint monitoring mechanism, traffic type and other factors such as features, cost etc. and choose the one that best suits your need.

Azure Traffic Manager is a DNS-based traffic load balancer, which supports HTTP, HTTPS, or TCP endpoint monitoring but HTTPS monitoring doesn't verify whether your TLS/SSL certificate is valid--it only checks that the certificate is present. Front Door works at Layer 7 (HTTP/HTTPS layer) and supports sending probes over either HTTP or HTTPS protocols.

Both Traffic Manager and Front Door supports **Priority-based traffic-routing**, which is used when you want to have a primary service endpoint for all traffic and can provide multiple backup endpoints in case the primary or one of the backup endpoints is unavailable.

Refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods#priority-traffic-routing-method

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-routing-methods#priority-based-traffic-routing

To integrate your Azure App Service with Azure Traffic manager, please follow:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-traffic-manager

Then, you can set the routing method to Priority in the configuration tab of Traffic manager profile.

To integrate your Azure App Service with Azure Front Door, please follow:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/quickstart-create-front-door

You can add the Priorities in the backends while configuring the Azure Front Door.